# differential geometry about neither local isometry nor conformal map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

hi I need help in geometry I try to get the the idea but I couldn't solve so. It becomes great if someone try solve with explain to me by using figures if possible. I see this question change a lot of geometry experts and thank you for trying to solve.
the question

> > (Lambert’s cylindrical projection) Project the unit sphere (except for the north and south poles) radially outward to the cylinder of radius $1$ by sending $(x,y,z)$ to $(x/\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)},y/\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)},z)$
>
> Check that this map preserves area, but is neither a local isometry nor conformal.

**Hint:** Let $x(u,v)$ be the spherical coordinates parametrization of the sphere, and consider $x^*(u,v)=(cos(v),sin(v),cos(u)$}

Thank you very much
thanks

Comment: This goes back to Archimedes. What do you understand so far? What condition would tell you that a mapping from one surface to another preserved area? And, what book are you using?

Comment: Maybe this will work. This is the image Archimedes wanted on his tombstone: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Archimedes_sphere_and_cylinder.svg

Comment: And believed discovery, later, by the Roman, Cicero: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cicero_Discovering_the_Tomb_of_Archimedes_by_Benjamin_West.jpeg

Comment: the book name elementary differential geometry 2nd edition by springer

Comment: I didnot get the idea also if anyone expert i hope help me to solve and explain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use spherical coordinates $\phi$, $\theta$, where $\theta=0$ on the equator, and produce corresponding points on the sphere $S^2$ and the cylinder $C$ as follows:
$$\eqalign{(\phi,\theta)\mapsto{\bf r}(\phi,\theta)&:=(\cos\phi\cos\theta,\sin\phi\cos\theta, \sin\theta)\ ,\cr 
(\phi,\theta)\mapsto{\bf f}(\phi,\theta)&:=(\cos\phi,\sin\phi, \sin\theta)\ .\cr}$$
In this way Lambert's projection $L$ appears as
$$L:\ S^2\to C\ ,\qquad  {\bf r}(\phi,\theta)\to{\bf f}(\phi,\theta)\ .$$
Then compute
$$\eqalign{{\bf r}_\phi&=(-\sin\phi\cos\theta,\cos\phi\cos\theta,0),\quad {\bf r}_\theta=(-\cos\phi\sin\theta,-\sin\phi\sin\theta,\cos\theta),\cr
{\bf f}_\phi&=(-\sin\phi,\cos\phi,0),\quad {\bf f}_\theta=(0,0,\cos\theta)\ .\cr}$$
The fact that $$|{\bf r}_\phi|=\cos\theta\ne 1=|{\bf f}_\phi|\qquad(\theta\ne0)\tag{1}$$
already proves that $L$ is **not** an isometry: Equation (1) says that a piece of parallel at latitude $\theta$ on the sphere has length $$\int_{\phi_0}^{\phi_1}|{\bf r}_\phi|\ d\phi=(\phi_1-\phi_0)\cos\theta\ ,$$ while the projected arc has length $(\phi_1-\phi_0)$, given that $\phi_1>\phi_0$. Second, from
$$ {|{\bf r}_\phi|/|{\bf f}_\phi|\over |{\bf r}_\theta|/|{\bf f}_\theta|}=\cos^2\theta\ne1\qquad(\theta\ne0)\tag{2}$$
one then deduces that the projection cannot be conformal, even though the right angle between ${\bf r}_\phi$ and ${\bf r}_\theta$ is preserved. Equation $(2)$ says that at any point ${\bf p}:={\bf r}(\phi,\theta)\in S^2$ where $\theta\ne0$ the local dilatations of the parallel and the meridian through ${\bf p}$ under $L$ are different. For a conformal map the dilatations in **all** directions emanating from ${\bf p}$ would have to be equal.

Finally one computes
$$|{\bf r}_\phi\times{\bf r}_\theta|=\cos\theta=|{\bf f}_\phi\times{\bf f}_\theta|\ .$$
This shows that to an infinitesimal rectangle in the parameter plane correspond isoareal infinitesimal rectangles on $S^2$, resp. $C$. Therefore the projection is area-preserving.

Comment: thank you so much for answer

Comment: thank you so much for answer but how show it is local isometry can you please check it is not local isometry thanks

Comment: can you please show with more explain and using figures

Comment: @leena adam: See my edit. Sorry, no figures.